# Read text from file and edit it in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I´ve just started to learn Haskell. I want to write a program, which reads a text file, edits it (changes the word combination "@@ersetzeMich@@" on "@@icWurdeErsetzt@@") and writes the edited text in another file.
I wrote a code, but it doesn't function, as it should.

```
main = do
    contents <- readFile "input.txt"
    let newContents = map (\c -> if c == "@@ersetzeMich@@" then "@@icWurdeErsetzt@@" else c) $ [contents]
    writeFile "output.txt" newContents
```

I would be grateful, if you could help me and say, how I can modify or change my code.

Comment: I think you need to split the file contents into *words* first. Maybe there is a function for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use the `text` package, then you can do this easily with `replace`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

main = do
    contents <- T.readFile "input.txt"
    let newContents = T.replace "@@ersetzeMich@@" "@@icWurdeErsetzt@@" contents
    T.writeFile "output.txt" newContents
```

If you want to stick with the `String` type but are willing to use other third-party packages, then you can use [`Data.List.Extra.replace` from the `extra` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.12/docs/Data-List-Extra.html#v:replace) in the exact same way.

By the way, `map f $ [x]` is just an overcomplicated version of `[f x]`.